# C++ String manipulation isn't making sense to me

Tags: c++, string, programming-languages

This particular assignment has to do with removing substrings from strings; I am trying some of the Stanford SEE courses online to learn some new languages.

What I've got so far is below, but if `text = "hello hello"` and `remove ="el"`, it gets stuck in a loop, but if i change text to `text = "hello hllo"`, it works, making me think I'm doing something obviously stupid.

There is a stipulation in the assignment not to modify the incoming strings, and instead to return a new string.

```
string CensorString1(string text, string remove){
    string returned;
    size_t found=0, lastfound=0;
    found = (text.substr(lastfound,text.size())).find(remove);
    while (string::npos != found ){
        returned += text.substr(lastfound,found);
        lastfound = found + remove.size();
        found = (text.substr(lastfound,text.size())).find(remove);
    }
    returned += text.substr(lastfound,found);
    return returned;
}
```

Guidance would be appreciated :-) Thanks

**UPDATE**

Took the very kind advice given and modified my code to this :

```
string CensorString1(string text, string remove){
string returned;
size_t found=0, lastfound=0;
found = text.find(remove);
while (string::npos != found ){
    returned += text.substr(lastfound,found);
    lastfound = found + remove.length();
    found = text.find(remove,lastfound);
}
returned += text.substr(lastfound);
return returned;
}
```

But still behaves the same

Any more ideas folks?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`found = (text.substr(lastfound,text.size())).find(remove);` is incorrect. It returns the index of the searched string in `text.substr(lastfound,text.size())`, but not in `text`.

You should perhaps change this to `found = text.find(text, lastfound);`.

Besides of being incorrect, taking a substring (this means, allocating a new string) and calculating an index in it is quite inefficient, unless the optimizer is super-smart.

Moreover, the final `returned += text.substr(lastfound,found);` is incorrect too: you need to add the last chunk of the text, not the one till `found` index (which is most likely empty, as `lastfound` can be smaller than `found`. Better would be `returned += text.substr(lastfound);`

Edit:
In the second example, you need to replace `returned += text.substr(lastfound,found);`
 with `returned += text.substr(lastfound,found-lastfound);`. The second argument to `substr` is length, not position.

With this change, the test example runs fine in my test program.

(Addition by J.F. Sebastian:)

```
string CensorString1(string const& text, string const& remove){
  string returned;
  size_t found = string::npos, lastfound = 0;
  do {
    found = text.find(remove, lastfound);
    returned += text.substr(lastfound, found-lastfound);
    lastfound = found + remove.size();
  } while(found != string::npos);
  return returned;
}
```

Comment: @Vlad, *facepalm* always consult the prototype... Thanks, enjoy a tick and upvote

Comment: @Vlad: It won't be negative, it will be large positive number (larger than `text.size()`) and it is a hack.

Comment: @Vlad @J.F. Sebastian After deeper consultation with the c++ reference [1], its apparently exactly what you're supposed to do. Thank you both for your help/interest.

[1]:http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/npos/

Answer (score 0):

`text.substr(lastfound,text.size())` begins somewhere in the middle of `text` and continues for the entire size of `text`. That doesn't make sense, although I suppose it works because of the wonky way these particular functions handle range errors. `string::npos` would state your intention better than `size`.

Generally speaking, the manipulation members of `string` are less elegant than the more general algorithms in `<algorithm>`. I recommend you use those instead, such as [`std::search`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/search/), along with `string::iterator` in place of integer offsets.

**UPDATE:** The same kind of error exists in the second example. Use `string::npos` for the second argument to `substr` to get the substring through the end.

Answer (score 0):

`found = (text.substr(lastfound,text.size())).find(remove);` starts counting for the `find()` function all over again at zero (i.e. the first character after the last match will have index 0, and it will look like the start of `text`). However, find can take 2 parameters, where the second parameter is the index to start at. So you can change this line to `found = text.find(remove,lastfound)`

More clearly:

```
text =                      hellohello
find "el" in here            ^ is at index 1 in `text`
substring after match          lohello
find "el" in here                 ^ is at index 3 in the substring
                                    but your program doesn't know
                                    that's actually index 6 in `text`
```